# How to automatically add a day every 24 hours in DateTime

Tags: c#

I'm writing a code where I can advance the current time by pressing Enter. I've managed to get that going, but I need the date to advance as well every 24 hours. Here's my code:

```
var time = new DateTime(2025, 4, 15, 12, 00, 0);

string currentDate = time.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
string currentTime = time.ToString("HH:mm");
int timeAdd = 4;

Console.WriteLine("Press 'Enter' to advance...");
ConsoleKeyInfo userInput = Console.ReadKey();

if (userInput.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter) {
currentTime = time.AddHours(timeAdd).ToString("HH:mm");
timeAdd = timeAdd + 4;
```

This is working fine, but at 00:00 everyday (or if I advance the time at for example 22:00 for 3 hours then at 01:00) the day value should also increase by one. At the end of every month the month should increase too, and then the year.

An optional question to answer is; Is there a better way to advance the time? As you see, right now I'm advancing the time by first 4, then 8, then 12 and so on, hours. That's because as I can't set the time to anything after it's declared, i have to add 4 additional hours each time.

Edit: This isn't the full code and it's in a while loop, I've decided to include only the necessary parts for the question.

Comment: "*I can't set the time to anything after it's declared*" - Why is that? If you want to update the date, just re-assign `currentDate` as you did at the beginning of the snippet.

Comment: Then for that I need to check if a day has passed, and my question asks just that. Also, I meant I can't change the DateTime method after it's declared. So if I just did 
`currentTime = time.AddHours(4).ToString("HH:mm");`
it would output first 12:00, then 16:00, and then 16:00 over and over again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `DateTime` is an immutable structure. Every method that should modify it returns a new instance, and you are throwing it away.
Use this instead:

```
var time = new DateTime(2025, 4, 15, 12, 00, 0);

string currentDate = time.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
string currentTime = time.ToString("HH:mm");
int timeAdd = 4;

Console.WriteLine("Press 'Enter' to advance...");
ConsoleKeyInfo userInput = Console.ReadKey();

if (userInput.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter) 
{
    time = time.AddHours(timeAdd);
    currentDate = time.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); // refresh date
    currentTime = time.ToString("HH:mm"); // refresh time
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it answered my optional question perfectly. Though my main question stands.

Comment: @AcedPI Not sure what you mean by that. `AddHours` automatically adds days.  Setting `currentDate = time.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` again should show you that

Comment: Thank you very much. That solves my main problem. I suggest that you include this comment in your post for convenience, I will mark it as the answer. Thank you again.